# Sending proper error reponse from nodejs expressjs

Tags: node.js, express

I'm trying to return custom error response for `ajax` request, this is meant to return `Session Expired` response.  How can i send back proper `error` response.
As of now i'm  getting `statusText` as `unknown`

```
res.status(440).json({
      success : false,
      error   : 'Session Expired'
});
```

### Url Status

`GET https://domain.com/home 440 (unknown)`

### JSON Response

```
{readyState: 4, responseText: "{"success":false,"error":"Session Expired"}", responseJSON: Object, status: 440, statusText: "unknown"}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can enrich the previous answer by adding both a "reason phrase" and json content, eg:

```
res.writeHead(440, 'my error reason phrase', {'content-type':'application/json'});
res.end(JSON.stringify({someProp: 'someValue'}));
```